# Proper DDD way to create and remove child in oneToMany relation?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, one-to-many, referential-integrity

I am struggling to find the proper DDD way to have a parent/child oneToMany relationship that:

- Ensures entities cannot exist in invalid state
- Exposes no unwanted methods (i.e. a clean API)

I am using PHP and Doctrine2 but I guess this applies to many other languages/platforms as well. Here's my base entity code. I have `Parent` and `Child` objects. A `Child` cannot exist without a parent.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ParentClass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $children;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Child
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Base", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

But how should I create and remove child entities?

To enfore consistency I could have the parent as a constructor parameter for Child:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public function addChild(Child $child)
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

    public function removeChild(Child $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function __construct(ParentClass $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
        $this->parent->addChild($this);
    }
}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$child = new Child($parent);
```

The problem with this is that it exposes addChild which really shouldn't be used by developers now. It would need a whole load of extra checks to ensure you cannot move children between parents.

As an alternative I could use a setter:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public function addChild(Child $child)
    {
        $child->setParent($this);
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

    public function removeChild(Child $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function setParent(ParentClass $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$parent->addChild(new Child());
```

The problem here is that Child would be in an invalid state until you call addChild.

A third option could be to have addChild create a new child:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public function addChild()
    {
        $child = new Child($parent);
        $this->children[] = $child;
        return $child;
    }

    public function removeChild(Child $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function __construct(ParentClass $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$child = $parent->addChild();
```

The problem with this is that the child constructor is exposed to developers. Also, my (Symfony) form library is probably going to hate me, causing me to have a bunch of DTO's and mappers just for a simple use case.

There are probably even more possible ways to handle this. What is the preferred way to ensure a clean domain model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensuring a clean Domain model means you ignore everything db related, like one to many relationships. Your parent/child issue is a smell, a hint that you're using db driven design.

At the Domain level, the Aggregate Root (AR) acts as the 'parent', although the term is wrong. An Aggregate represents a domain concept, while the AR is in charge of ensuring its **consistency** . The 'children' are elements without which the concept can't exist. You'll always be using the AR to work with the 'children', because this is the only way you can ensure consistency. Basically, the AR is in charge of creating the actual 'children' objects.

Treating an AR like a container is an anti-pattern. **Has** in DDD means, **it's defined by**, not *it contains* . I've wrote [some](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2013/01/15/Domain-Driven-Design-Aggregate-Root-Modelling-Fallacy.aspx/) [posts](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2013/10/18/Modelling-Aggregate-Roots-Relationships.aspx/) about it some years ago but they're still valid.

Your Symfony form library shouldn't hate you, because that's a **UI** concern, not a Domain one. You should use a specific view model / input that will be sent to an application service which will use it to create/update the domain model. If you can use directly the domain model for UI purposes, then maybe all you have is just a CRUD app where you don't need DDD.

Comment: I always wonder why there isn't a possible implementation answer for the exact question. Instead many complain persistence is not a part of DDD and stop answering how to address the problem. While its true that DDD doesn't care about persistence, practically there will be a solution for the problem(as DDD is applied in many successful projects) on how to approach it.